# Как поменять домашнюю страницу Yii2

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Как сделать так чтобы при переходе на корневой адрес без добавления /web осуществлялся переход на нужный контроллер

Answer (score 0):

Можно в конфиге установить путь по умолчанию

```
'defaultRoute' => 'user/index'
```